# Protecting admin directory from search engines like google

Tags: php

I have a website folder e.g mywebsite and my admin panel is inside that folder along with other directories like ajax, jquery etc etc,  i was wondering, whether there is any way i can hide my admin directory from search engines as once that directory is accessed, webserver automatically point to index page which has a login form, which i am securing through encryption, but that is a risk i guess, please provide me any links or any other useful suggestion to prevent something like above.

Thank you

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Block-Search-Engines - Check that out, it may help.

Comment: google for robots.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword here is `robots.txt`

More information on:

- http://www.robotstxt.org/
- http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449

Remember that this is only a **recommendation**; malicious bots/crawlers/spiders could scan/find/discover the directory anyway. On the downside: malicious bots/crawlers/spiders will use exactly this file to quickly discover which directories aren't supposed to be 'discovered'. What you need is a login mechanism, not a way to "hide" the admin directory.

You can also resort (as [mentioned by Harry Beasant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15660154/215042)) to a .htaccess but this *also* simply excludes searchengines and not malicious users (and, specifically Harry Beasant's "answer" also causes another *innocent* site to get unwanted traffic [image: not cool]... seriously uncool). Also: a lot of searchengines won't get rewritten; so this might solve your "problem" for Google/MSN/... but not, for example, Bing or Baidu (two major players in the searchengine world). Finally, what Harry left out (or didn't specifically mention), is that you need to put this .htaccess *in the admin directory*; if you accidentilly put it in your sites root the site will disappear from those searchengines completely. Your hard-earned reputation out the window with a tiny mistake [image: bye bye]. Very dangerous if you ask me.

Disabling directory listings (as [mentioned by Squeezy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15660178/215042)) is *always* a good idea, not only for admin directories. But, again, this doesn't prevent malicious users to "discover" your admin directory.

Just **don't rely on [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)** and get yourself a decent login mechanism in place.

Comment: Yes Robill i know, i've made a login system for that for which i am using md5 within another md5.. that would be good for a normal site, i was checking my university site the other day and i came through this thing and i then thought this thing is important too ...

Comment: No, no, no, no, nooooo! MD5 is **not** a good idea and "md5 within another md5" is even **worse** (you loose entropy)! You **really** need to read up on this topic; you need at least a decent hash function like SHA256 and a `salt` but better yet: use [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2). Forget about google indexing your admin directory for a minute and **focus on this first**! I can't stress this enough. MD5 is close to useless, [especially if you're not using a salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).

Comment: OMG... nOW What :( i ve used it every where in the project ... i mean these things get cracked every day and new ones come out the next day, omg,

Comment: *"OMG... nOW What"* As said: drop everything you're doing and **fix this first**. Unfortunately many, *many* websites have outright wrong or very outdated information on this topic (PHP sites even more than others in my experience) and so if you're new to this you can't be blamed too hard for this. Then again: a login system (protecting your & your user's data amongst one of the main reasons for a login system in the first place) is usually an *important* part of the entire system so make sure you get it right! For a good start; use these sites: http://goo.gl/XzwCJ and http://goo.gl/VRqFU.

Comment: many many thanx for the good suggestion bro, i really appreciate it, i need to re work on this password thing first, will see with the directory afterwards ... many thanx again...

Answer (score 0):

Its best to use a .htaccess file to protect the directory;

You could do something like;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AltaVista [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} msnbot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Slurp
RewriteRule ^.*$ "http\:\/\/htmlremix\.com" [R=301,L]
```

This would block the search engine bots from indexing it.

Comment: Thanx Harry .. will do that :)

Comment: htmlremix.com will thank you for that... Read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15660148/215042) for an explanation. Also: this doesn't solve the *actual* problem. Again: see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't put a link to your admin panel you should be safe. Make sure there is no directory listing enabled for parent folders either.

A typical search engine will not *guess* your directories.
Actually, putting up a robots.txt will expose your directory to scanners (because it is mentioned there) instead of having it at an undisclosed location.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the /robots.txt file, which can be configured to exclude specific directories from search engines. You might use something like:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
```

(supposing the directory you want to exclude is named `admin`). This will tell to the bots not to access it, but of course it wont prevent them to do it if they really want to... (of course "good" search engines respect this standard).